# Basic representation of a simple Lie algebra and its highest weight

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras, verma-modules, kac-moody-algebras

I have come across the terms "basic representation" of a semisimple Lie algebra, but I am finding it hard to find a clear definition of this representation. Can someone provide me a reference or explain to me what this concept is?

1. How is the "basic representation" of a (say simple) Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ defined?
2. This is supposedly a highest weight representation. What highest weight does this correspond to? Is there a formula or a list I can refer to get these highest weights?
3. How do these formulas/definition generalize to Kac-moody Lie algebras?

Comment: 1. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487670/fundamental-representations-of-lie-algebras). It is also called *fundamental representation*. 2. Yes, it is.